# Sorting list of tuples with CustomComparer

Tags: c#, list, sorting, tuples

I had the following situation which works fine:

```
var data = new List<MyData>();
data.Sort(new MyCustomComparer())   //IComparer<MyData>
```

Now I need to save additional information in the list but still use the same CustomComparer (only sort by second value of tuple):

```
var data = new List<Tuple<SomeData, MyData>>();
data.Sort(new MyCostumComparer());      //won´t work
```

SomeData is irrelevant for the sorting but I need it in the sorted list.
What is the best way to do this without changing the Comparer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sorted = data.OrderBy(x => x.Item2, new MyCustomComparer());
```

Comment: Definitely better answer than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 var lookup = data.ToLookup(x => x.Item2);
 data.Select(x => x.Item2).OrderBy(x => x, new MyCustomComparer()).Select(x => lookup[x]).ToList();
```